# Make container just a bit larger than child?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to make a container be a bit larger than its child without hard coding width and height? I have a row of 3 images that need to show a different colored background when clicked, but I don't want the background to be too tight on the image.

Here's what the code currently looks like:

```
  Widget chooseImage(){
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .175),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            onTap: () => setState(() => _imageChoice == 1 ? _imageChoice = 0 : _imageChoice = 1),
            child: Container(
              color: _imageChoice == 1 ? blue : Colors.white,
              child: Image.asset("assets/creamG.png"),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () => setState(() => _imageChoice == 2 ? _imageChoice = 0 : _imageChoice = 2),
            child: Container(
              color: _imageChoice == 2 ? blue : Colors.white,
              child: Image.asset("assets/moisturizerG.png"),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () => setState(() => _imageChoice == 3 ? _imageChoice = 0 : _imageChoice = 3),
            child: Container(
              color: _imageChoice == 3 ? blue : Colors.white,
              child: Image.asset("assets/pillG.png"),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
    );
  }
```

And here is what the UI looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r74xB.jpg
I want that blue background to have some padding between the edges and the actual image.

Comment: did you tried padding property  ?

Comment: Oh yikes! I did try it but on the wrong container. Thanks for making me try it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert `FractionallySizedBox` widget between your parent and child widget.

```
FractionallySizedBox(
  widthFactor: 0.98,
  heightFactor: 0.98,
  child: YourChild(),
),
```

In this example child widget will take 98% of the width and height of your parent widget.